# Visual Studio 2015 All variables do not exist in the current context for web projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Found a couple similar issues with older versions of VS, but either those didn't work or the same options are not available.

Create a new .Net 5 web app and every variable says The Name '...' does not exist in the current context. I tried creating a console app and everything works fine.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var a = 1;
        var b = a;
        return View();
    }
```

Add a watch to a/b or hover over them with a breakpoint on return View and I get nothing.

Have tried switching to Release and back along with setting the cpu to x86. Of course restarted VS and created multiple projects, but just lost at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same issue after updating to VS Update 2 while working on an ASP.NET 5 project.

It seems to be a bug with the update. There's a patch that solved the problem for me. Found the solution in this discussion (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1038150/visual-studio-2015-debugger-doesnt-recognize-a-variable).

If you can't see the update directly in VS, you can download the patch from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=785969&clcid=0x409.